# How to share a private Bitbucket repository via link?

Tags: bitbucket

Is it possible to share a private repository with other users on a bitbucket by sending a link? I do not mean the "Add user and group access" option, because I know who exactly will be the recipient. I can only send a link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the link to the repository is restricted to people who have been added to the repository. If you want to share a link to the repo without adding someone it needs to be public.

If you just want to share the code upload a zip to Google Drive and share that.

Answer (score 2):

You may share the link publicly by changing the settings from Private to Public under Repository details which can be seen after clicking settings on your repository.

[image: Repository Settings]

Comment: Thanks. I'm just new here that's why I wasn't able to show what I just uploaded

Comment: If your project is private, please do it as a public project, otherwise repository check box may be disabled